# Star Rating in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a star rating system please check the JSFiddle .I want to stick the rating on mouse click.

HTML:

```
<div class="rating-star rating-star-off" data-value="0"></div>
<div class="rating-star rating-star-off" data-value="1"></div>
<div class="rating-star rating-star-off" data-value="2"></div>
<div class="rating-star rating-star-off" data-value="3"></div>
<div class="rating-star rating-star-off" data-value="4"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rating-star{width:25px;height:25px;float:left;margin-right:5px;}
.rating-star-off{background:#eee url(star-off.svg) no-repeat;}
.rating-star-on{background:#000 url(star-on.svg) no-repeat;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

  $(".rating-star").click(function(e){
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('rating-star-on');
    $(this).nextAll().removeClass('rating-star-on');
  });
  $(".rating-star").hover(function(){
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('rating-star-on');
    $(this).nextAll().removeClass('rating-star-on');
  });
  $(".rating-star").mouseout(function(){
    $(".rating-star").removeClass('rating-star-on'); 
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/piyush_dezi/a67gv2o7/

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the question or problem?

Comment: add simple if else statement to click and mouseout

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add another class for `selected` to your css rules

```
.rating-star-on, 
.rating-star-selected
    {background:#000 url(star-on.svg) no-repeat;}
```

And change the click handler to add this selected class.

```
$(".rating-star").click(function(e){
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('rating-star-selected');
    $(this).nextAll().removeClass('rating-star-on');
});
```

You will likely need to make some adjustments if you want user to be able to change their rating also

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a67gv2o7/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks a lot charlietfl for your suggestion it's work now.

Answer (score 0):

First your click event add classes to highlight the stars after it mouse out event remove these classes. In mouse click event unbind mouse out event so it will not remove classes from your stars. Also instead of using anonymous mouse out function use name function so your can bind it again for other starts.

```
   $(function(){
$(".rating-star").mouseout(mouseOutFunction);

function mouseOutFunction(){
$(".rating-star").removeClass('rating-star-on'); 
}


$(".rating-star").click(function(e){
$(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('rating-star-on');
$(this).nextAll().removeClass('rating-star-on');
$(".rating-star").bind( "mouseout", mouseOutFunction);
$(this).unbind( "mouseout" );
});

$(".rating-star").mouseenter(function(){

  $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('rating-star-on');
  $(this).nextAll().removeClass('rating-star-on');
});

});
```

Comment: that order is absolutely meaningless. It's the order that events occur that matters, not the order that you assign them

Comment: I have found the real problem here first function is not working in this code. He has click function here and it is not working. I have move this function in the end and now hover function is not working.

Comment: OK.. I see why...  the `hover` single callback fires for both `enter` and `leave` when only one function argument is given. So your order is fixing it but only because of bad choice of events by OP. There are actually 2 mouseout changes of class occuring

Comment: Thanks charlief I have found the real problem and solved it. I am editing the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to CSS:

```
.rating-star-hover {background:#000 url(star-on.svg) no-repeat;}
```

Update JS:

```
$(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('rating-star-off').addClass('rating-star-on');
$(this).nextAll().removeClass('rating-star-on');
});

$(".rating-star").hover(function(){
  $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('rating-star-hover');
  $(this).nextAll().removeClass('rating-star-on');
});

$(".rating-star").mouseout(function(){
    $(".rating-star").removeClass('rating-star-hover'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not getting executed is that when we click on the div, the rating-on class is added but as we mouseout the class is been removed. So the rating class is not changed.
You can also do this using an boolean variable. 
Check this :

```
    `http://jsfiddle.net/bandhavya/we3mx6vt/`
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use jquery rating plugin ? Have many options in the web. Like raty.check this url: [Rating Plugins](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-rating-plugin/)
Raty is one of the best that i used.